# Как получить ЛОКАЛЬНЫЙ адрес компьютера?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скажите пожалуйста, с помощью `import geoip2.database` и `request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')` я получаю внешний IP, а как мне получить локальный адрес компа?
Именно компа, а не хоста и т.д., потому что на него я буду регат пользователей.

ПС MAC адрес не подходит, т.к. бывают недопонимания с провайдерами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```py
import socket

def local_ip():
    # Получаем локальный IP
    local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    if local_ip == "192.168.244.1":
        return "Err (192.168.244.1)"
    return local_ip
```

192.168.244.1 обычно определяет при отсутствии сети. Наверное можно этот момент обработать более правильно, но и так все работает.

Для получения уникального ID.

```py
import subprocess
m_id = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')[1].strip()
print(m_id)
```

Comment: Я возможно не до конца объяснил ситуацию, мне нужно, чтобы был уникальный адрес для каждого компьютера. А если буду адрес хоста, то уникальность каждого уст-ва пропадает.

Comment: а Вы понимаете разницу между хостом и компьютером?

Comment: в результате вашего решения, к одному адресу может быть привязано несколько устройств

Comment: это не то, что мне нужно

Comment: м, может Вам нужен клиентский адрес, а не серверный?

Comment: Да-да, это то что мне нужно - клиентский адрес устройства. Только вот не знаю какой выбрать, за этим собственно обратился)

Comment: вернее, как его получить

Comment: ну как минимум это уже не локальный адрес компа(ВАШ текущий IP на сетевой карте). Как понимаю вам нужны адреса удаленных машин(клиентов)? и тогда вам нужны уже уникальные идентификаторы... Добавил вариант в ответ.

Comment: А каким образом к вам будут подключаться  клиенты?  Если скриптом то все прекрасно, а если через браузер то там немного другая история будет.

Comment: Но через браузер получить именно локальный адрес клиента, который при этом за натом может быть малось накладно. Но никто не мешает им прислать этот самый адрес Вам. Хотя он у них может меняться постоянно. Лучше использовать классические решения - куки или другой fingerprinting.

Comment: В том и сложность что браузер на даст доступ к железу(без бубна), а куки и тд.. могут внезапно пропасть что будет равно утере учетки.. fingerprinting не уверен но может меняться от настроек приватности браузера. Но браузер это пока так домыслы, может там просто клиентский скрипт и все.

Comment: тогда может делать обычное приложение или не заморачиваться и сделать обычную регистрацию по старинке

Comment: Вы правы. Всё-таки придётся воспользоваться куками.